# While creating api with nodejs, reference error: schema is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to reach information with get method on Postman. But whenever i "localhost:3000/api/mekanlar/***mekan's objectid***", i get reference error "Mekan is not defined". Here is my mekansema.js file in /app_api/models.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var saatSema = new mongoose.Schema({
  gunler: {type: String, required: true},
  acilis: String,
  kapanis: String,
  kapali: {type: Boolean, required: true} 
});

var yorumSema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ad: String,
  puan: {type: Number, required: true, min:0, max:5},
  yorumMetni: String,
  saat: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var mekanSema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ad: {type: String, required: true},
  adres: String,
  puan: {type: Number, default:0, min:0, max:5},
  imkanlar: [String],
  mesafe: {type: [Number], index:'2dsphere'},
  saat: [saatSema],
  yorumlar: [yorumSema]
});
mongoose.model('Mekan', mekanSema, 'Mekanlar');
```

and mekanlar.js file in /app_api/controllers

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mekan = mongoose.model('Mekan');

var jsonCevapYolla = function(res, status, content){
  res.status(status);
  res.json(content);
};
module.exports.mekanGetir = function(req, res){
if (req.params && req.params.mekanid){
Mekan
 .findById(req.params.mekanid)
 .exec(function(hata, mekan){
if(!mekan){
  jsonCevapYolla(res, 404, {
      "mesaj" : "mekanid bulunamadı."
});
return;
}
else if(hata){
jsonCevapYolla(res, 404, hata);
return;
}
jsonCevapYolla(res, 200, mekan);
});
}
else{
   jsonCevapYolla(res, 404, {
     "mesaj" : "istekte mekanid yok"
   });
}
};
```

and this is index.js in /app_api/routes.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlMekanlar = require('../controllers/mekanlar');
var ctrlYorumlar = require('../controllers/yorumlar');

//Mekan Rotaları
//router.get('/mekanlar', ctrlMekanlar.mekanlariListele);
//router.post('/mekanlar', ctrlMekanlar.mekanEkle);
router.get('/mekanlar/:mekanid', ctrlMekanlar.mekanGetir);
//router.put('/mekanlar/:mekanid', ctrlMekanlar.mekanGuncelle);
//router.delete('/mekanlar/:mekanid', ctrlMekanlar.mekanSil);

//Yorum Rotaları
//router.post('/mekanlar/:mekanid/yorumlar', ctrlYorumlar.yorumEkle);
//router.get('/mekanlar/:mekanid/yorumlar/:yorumid',    ctrlYorumlar.yorumGetir);
//router.put('/mekanlar/:mekanid/yorumlar/:yorumid',    ctrlYorumlar.yorumGuncelle);
//router.delete('/mekanlar/:mekanid/yorumlar/:yorumid', ctrlYorumlar.yorumSil);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's difficult to see where the problem is, since you don't provide a stack trace.  but I think at this line:

```
Mekan
 .findById(req.params.mekanid)
```

`Mekan` should be `mekan`.

Comment: Thanks man. I should be blind. I can't figure it out for a while. Thank you again!